# IdentityServer Offline Login Practices

Tags: authentication, xamarin, asp.net-core, xamarin.forms, identityserver4

I know this might be a very unusual question but I have been using IdentityServer 4 on .Net Core 2.1 for quite a while, serving all sorts of different APIs/Clients/Mobile Apps with connection to the internet at 'all times'.

Now I have encountered an interesting scenario where a User will have access to the internet and be able to authenticate with IdentityServer once but might not have access to internet after an X amount of time (X could be minutes/hours/days), but I still need to authenticate that user and login to use the 'offline features' of the app (even after closing the app).

I have thought about caching some credentials to then verify that the user is valid or using a system where I send an SMS code to then verify the user has the right phone (But that will only work if the app is on a mobile device, hence, not ideal). I'm still not set on any of the options.

I just wanted to ask if anyone else has encountered a similar problem like this, any suggestions would be appreciated. Please have in mind that the user may be logged out after using the app and still needs to be authenticated even if there is no internet connection. I like IdentityServer4 quite a lot, so I will prefer to keep it that way, and My App is developed using Xamarin Forms (iOS, Android, UWP), and the IdentityServer instance is on the cloud.

Thanks a lot for the help, any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only your service will know how to authenticate someone using their server-side credentials how about using the local secure platform features of the device (Secure Enclave, SafetyNet, whatever Windows does)?

The end result is that the user can use their already-configured PIN / fingerprint / faceprint to access your app, all backed by tamper-proof security hardware.

This also gives you the option to allow users to sign in only using their local credential by unlocking a previously stored refresh token. My banking app works like this for example - modern phones are really quite secure by default.

If you want to get fancy you could also enroll their device as a WebAuthn authenticator in your IdentityServer4 service and they could then use the same method to authenticate with the server when necessary.